# Como evitar el scroll top al momento de cambiar el estado? React

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

Les cuento el problema.
Estoy utilizando un template el cual tiene algunos custom hook como el siguiente:

```
import {useCallback, useState} from 'react';
import _ from '@lodash';

function useForm(initialState, onSubmit)
{
    const [form, setForm] = useState(initialState);

    const handleChange = useCallback((event) => {
        event.persist();
        setForm(
            form => ({
                ...form,
                [event.target.name]: event.target.type === 'checkbox' ? event.target.checked : event.target.value
            })
        );
    }, []);

    const resetForm = useCallback(() => {
        setForm(initialState);
    }, [initialState]);

    const setInForm = useCallback((name, value) => {
        setForm(form => _.setIn(form, name, value));
    }, []);

    const handleSubmit = useCallback((event) => {
        if ( event )
        {
            event.preventDefault();
        }
        if ( onSubmit )
        {
            onSubmit();
        }
    }, [onSubmit]);

    return {
        form,
        handleChange,
        handleSubmit,
        resetForm,
        setForm,
        setInForm
    }
}

export default useForm;
```

Sucede que al tener un formulario largo, al momento de utilizar el `handleChange` o el `setForm` la página dispara una nueva renderización y mi formulario automaticamente vuelve al comienzo.

```
const Person = (props) => {
    const dispatch  = useDispatch();
    const styles    = useStyles();
    const person    = useSelector(({Persons}) => Persons.person);
    const {form, handleChange, setForm} = useForm(null);
    const [tabValue, setTabValue] = useState(0);


    useEffect(() => {
        const updatePersonState = () =>
        {
            const params = props.match.params;
            const {personId} = params;

            if ( personId === 'new' )
            {
                dispatch(Actions.newPerson());
            }
            else
            {
                dispatch(Actions.getPerson(props.match.params));
            }
        }

        updatePersonState();
    }, [dispatch, props.match.params]);

    useEffect(() => {
        //ME RENDERIZO CADA VEZ QUE ACTIVO HANDLECHANGE O SETFORM
        if (
            (person.data && !form) ||
            (person.data && form && person.data.id !== form.id)
        )
        {
            setForm(person.data);
        }

        console.log(form, person.data, setForm);
    }, [form, person.data, setForm]);
```

Dejo una parte del return como parte del formulario

```
return (
        <FusePageCarded
            classes={{
                toolbar: "p-0",
                header : "min-h-72 h-72 sm:h-136 sm:min-h-136"
            }}
            header={
                form && (
                    <div className="flex flex-1 w-full items-center justify-between">

                        <div className="flex flex-col items-start max-w-full">

                            <FuseAnimate animation="transition.slideRightIn" delay={300}>
                                <Typography className="normal-case flex items-center sm:mb-12" component={Link} role="button" to="/persons" color="inherit">
                                    <Icon className="mr-4 text-20">arrow_back</Icon>
                                    Personas
                                </Typography>
                            </FuseAnimate>

                            <div className="flex items-center max-w-full">
                                <div className="flex flex-col min-w-0">
                                    <FuseAnimate animation="transition.slideLeftIn" delay={300}>
                                        <Typography className="text-16 sm:text-20 truncate">
                                            {form.nombres ? `${form.nombres} ${form.apellido_paterno} ${form.apellido_materno}` : 'Nueva Persona'}
                                        </Typography>
                                    </FuseAnimate>
                                    <FuseAnimate animation="transition.slideLeftIn" delay={300}>
                                        <Typography variant="caption">Información</Typography>
                                    </FuseAnimate>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <FuseAnimate animation="transition.slideRightIn" delay={300}>
                            <Button
                                className="whitespace-no-wrap"
                                variant="contained"
                                disabled={!canBeSubmitted()}
                                onClick={() => dispatch(Actions.savePerson(form))}
                            >
                                Guardar
                            </Button>
                        </FuseAnimate>
                    </div>
                )
            }
            contentToolbar={
                <Tabs
                    value={tabValue}
                    onChange={handleChangeTab}
                    indicatorColor="secondary"
                    textColor="secondary"
                    variant="scrollable"
                    scrollButtons="auto"
                    classes={{root: "w-full h-64"}}
                >
                    <Tab className="h-64 normal-case" label="Personal"/>
                    <Tab className="h-64 normal-case" label="Adicional"/>
                </Tabs>
            }
            content={
                form && (
                    <div className="p-16 sm:p-24">
                        {tabValue === 0 &&
                        (
                            <div>
                                <Grid container spacing={3}>
                                    <Grid item xs={4}>
                                        <Select 
                                            value={form.pais_id}
                                            setForm={setForm}
                                            name={'pais_id'}
                                            label={'Nacionalidad'}
                                            options={options}
                                        />
                                    </Grid>

                                    <Grid item xs={4}>
                                        <TextField
                                            error={form.dni === ''}
                                            required
                                            label="Documento de identidad"
                                            autoFocus
                                            id="dni"
                                            name="dni"
                                            value={form.dni}
                                            onChange={handleChange}
                                            variant="outlined"
                                            fullWidth
                                        />
                                    </Grid>
                                </Grid>
```

Como puedo evitar que se produzca ese refresco/scroll al inicio del formulario?

Comment: La pregunta es interesante, si pudieras agregar código en vez de imágenes  [¿Cómo preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Editado por código.

Comment: Es difícil depurar el ejemplo, pero la razón por la que el segundo `useEffect` se dispara cada vez que se invoca a `handleChange` o `setForm`, es porque se están creando nuevas referencias para `form` en ambos métodos; entonces como el segundo `useEffect` tiene una dependencia al objeto `form`, y esta referencia es nueva después de invocar a `handleChange/setForm` esto le dice a reactJS que habrá un nuevo disparo.